# #[allow(unused_must_use)] for one line

Tags: rust

I have lines that return `Result`. The result does not matter and I don't want `unwrap()` or any logging. (The frequent failures are expected)

How can I silence the unused warnings for only these lines?

`#[allow(unused_must_use)]` seems to work when applied to fn level, but this does not work:

```
#[allow(unused_must_use)]
std::fs::remove_file(&path1);
#[allow(unused_must_use)]
std::fs::remove_file(&path2);
```

**Edit:**
while `let _ = ..` works as a workaround, `#[allow(unused..)]` specifically exists for this case, and the compiler also suggests to use it. Reading `let _ = ..` adds another layer of thinking. (assign and then abandon) So I prefer `#[allow(..)]` although it is more verbose. (If I see `let _ = ..` frequent enough and I get used to it, I may change my preference)

So I searched around and found some codes that apply macros to the statement level.
This question asks for why `#[allow(unused_must_use)]` for a line doesn't work-- wrong syntax? bug? just unimplemented yet for `unused_must_use`?

**Edit:**
According to this:

[How to quiet a warning for a single statement in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269408/how-to-quiet-a-warning-for-a-single-statement-in-rust)
My code should work.

Reading  these:

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/36675

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15701

I tried the allow on the scope level and it worked.

```
#[allow(unused_must_use)] {
    std::fs::remove_file(&path1);
    std::fs::remove_file(&path2);
}
```

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How to disable unused code warnings in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25877285/155423). TL;DR: `let _ = foo()`. If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: I believe this question is incorrectly marked as a duplicate of two other questions. It is related only in the sense that they are about silencing warnings. This question is specifically about a case for which a single line `allow` does not work. No answer in the other questions addresses this.

Comment: At time of writing, you still have to put a single statement in braces after the `#[allow(...)]`. As a one-line alternative, you can do `if std::fs::remove_file(&path1).is_err() {}`.